# mysql result retrieving a column name and value

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a function which converts a mysql query result in to an array

In the function below i'm assuming to have fields `isbn, title and rank` but this will not always be the case.

Is there a way to retrieve a fields name along with the value without actually knowing any of this information prior? so that this function can be used with any mysql query result.

**function**

```
function mysqlToArray($result){

   $arr = array();
   $numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);//count
   if($numRows>0){
      for($i=0; $i<$numRows; $i++){
         $arr[] = array(
            "isbn"      => mysql_result($result, $i, "isbn"),
            "title"     => mysql_result($result, $i, "title"),
            "rank"      => mysql_result($result, $i, "rank"),                   
         );
      }
   }        

   return $arr;
}
```

**example in use**

```
function getProfitableBooks(){
    $q = "SELECT isbn, title, rank FROM ".TBL_BOOKS;

    $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
    if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){  
        return null;
    }
    return $this->mysqlToArray($result);
}
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: @Matt thanks, im reading it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great PHP function for this `mysql_fetch_array`

You can [view examples mysql_fetch_array in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php).

Comment: Use of this extension is discouraged, it says so on the documentation

Comment: @mk_89: same thing for `mysql_query` that you are using.

Comment: It also says that for `mysql_query`, which you are using happily in the code in your question. Given that your query is static and accepts no user-editable input, you are not at risk of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: ok i remember I don't use mysql_fetch_array, it's because it only returns the first result of my query, I should be able to sort this out, thanks

Comment: It doesn't return only the first result. The problem is that probably you are not iterating through the results.

Comment: @hugohabel yeh I just realised that

Answer (score 2):

Try looking at this [mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Use of this extension is discouraged, it says so on the documentation

Comment: I agree, but you are not using PDO as far as I can see in your code.
mysql_query is also discouraged and you are using it. http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this to get the names of the cols.

```
my $table = 'name';
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE 1=0;");
$sth->execute;
my @cols = @{$sth->{NAME}}; # or NAME_lc if needed
$sth->finish;
foreach ( @cols ) {
    printf( "Note: col : %s\n", $_ );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)?

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) will be helpful here:

```
function mysqlToArray($result)
{
   $arr = array();
   while($arr[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

   return $arr;
}
```